# How to return the users message on a fallback intent?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a bot that answers question related to a certain topic. However, the user may say something that doesn't match with any intent I have. This phrases need to be stored on a database.

So far, I found out that I need to create a `fallback intent`. How can I make it so upon being triggered this intent returns a response with the text that triggered the intent?

Also, if I only have one fallback intent, will every missed match trigger it or do I have to link it in some way to all my intents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do something with the user input in a Fallback Intent is through your fulfillment webhook. In the [request object](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_request) that is sent, you can look at the `queryResult.queryText` parameter to get the text from the user. You can then send this as part of your [response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_response) as part of the `fulfillmentMessages` object.

You can't "attach" a Fallback Intent to a regular Intent. That doesn't actually make sense, since Intents represent what a user says, rather than the state of the conversation.

While there is a single Fallback Intent available, which can catch all no-match phrases, it is also possible to create Fallback Intents that only trigger if specific [input contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output) are set. If you have regular Intents with these same input contexts set, then the Fallback Intent with the context would catch anything they don't.